# At what Mars-time did Perseverance land?

Tags: mars, perseverance, time

The [Perseverance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover)) rover landed February 18, 2021 at 20:55 UTC, Earth-time. What time was it on Mars when Perseverance landed?

Comment: Which ["Mars calendar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeping_on_Mars) do you believe in? Event time or Earth receive time? (you have given Earth receive time) What time system? What representation in what time system? [Time is a messy construct...](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/Tutorials/pdf/individual_docs/15_time.pdf)

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 How about local solar time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perseverance landed in the late afternoon, at around 15:54 Local Mean Solar Time [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseverance_(rover)#Landing).

[This image](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/ELM_0000_0666952851_100ECM_N0000024LVS_04000_0000LUJ) taken at 15:51:55 by Perseverance's Lander Vision System Camera is from some way above the surface, [this one](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/FLR_0000_0666952977_663ECM_N0010044AUT_04096_00_2I3J) is on the ground at 15:53:58.